# png files displaying as different colors on iPad w/ retina display vs iPad Pro

Tags: ios, ipad

Is there an efficient or programmatic way to force .png files to display as the same color regardless of whether they are viewed on an iPad Pro or an iPad with a retina display (for my purposes, iPads 3 and higher that aren't a Pro)

My iPad app contains a large set of art that is basically just red and blue lines all saved as .png files. They are meant to be viewed with the most commonly available red/blue 3D glasses on the market. We can't change the physical glasses that people use to look at the app to get that pop out 3D effect.

The tolerance between all of the iPads with retina displays has been fine for our purposes. But once we run the app on an iPad Pro, the blue is no longer the same color blue as on the retina display.

This is with the iPad Pro brightness at max, and True Tone either on or off and Night Shift off (also tried it with Night Shift on but it is just a different blue)

Is the best solution to have all of the art re-created and use a UIDevice call to display one set for an iPad with retina display and another set of art for an iPad Pro?

The app is written entirely in Objective C and is for iPad only.

Comment: Have you gone down the (apparently frustrating) road of investigating color management for iPads? This may be relevant: https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/23936/photoshop-to-ipad-color-profile-woes/39106

Comment: That thread definitely describes a lot of the initial problems we had getting the art just right for our first release on retina display iPads. Our art is all created in Photoshop and we had a lot of back and forth with the artist to figure out how to get just the right blue and red to work with our grey background. But there are some links there that might lead to newer information so I'll keep reading through those. Thanks - JK